# Print all the hyperlinks records in Print Button click

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am currently using SQL Server Reporting Services 2005. I have a Report on the Report Manager which shows records and one of its column is HyperLink column, when i clicked any of the HyperLink column, it will open a PDF file in the browser.

Now i have received an update to have PRINT button on the Report and if User clicked on the PRINT button, the report should print all the HyperLink files in single click, is it possible to do in SSRS 2005, if yes, can anyone provide me the Steps to follow.

Below is the screenshot for an ex:

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Dani

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that you can add out-of-the-box to print anything by clicking a button. If you want to print something, you're going to have to write custom code. See this: [Reporting services: Print all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085498/reporting-services-print-all-pages)